# c++: union -> struct, explanation?

Tags: c++, typedef, unions

I have the following type definition:

```
typedef union{
unsigned int Entry;
struct {
    unsigned char EntryType;
    unsigned char EntryOffset[3];
};
} TLineDescriptor;
```

I also have the following use of the type:

```
TLineDescriptor LineDescriptor;
LineDescriptor.Entry = 40;
LineDescriptor.EntryType = 0x81;
```

`sizeof(LineDescriptor)` shows that this variable occupies 4 bytes of memory, which at first I assumed that it either held the int or the struct.

```
cout << LineDescriptor.Entry << " " << LineDescriptor.EntryType << endl;
```

However, the line above prints two different values, namely `129 ü`, `LineDescriptor.Entry` is apparently referring to the memory location where the value 0x81 was saved. I'm not sure what happened with the 40. 
But it is clear that my assumption was wrong. Can someone interpret and explain the type definition properly? Understanding it is crucial for me to working with the code I found.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not different values, actually. `129` is the character code for the character `ü`. The `operator <<` of the `ostream` treats `int` and `char` data types differently, printing the numerical value for the first one and the character value for the latter one.

So, your understanding of union types are correct. However, note that endianness could be an issue when dealing with union types. For example, on little-endian machines `EntryType` will hold the least significant byte of `Entry` and the `EntryOffset` array the others. But on big-endian machines, `EntryType` will hold the most significant byte.

Answer (score 1):

Print EntryType in this way:

```
cout << "0x" << hex << (unsigned)LineDescriptor.EntryType << endl;
```

and you will see that ü is 0x81.

Printing this:

```
cout << LineDescriptor.Entry
```

is undefined behavior - because only one element in union can be "active" at a moment - and your last assignment was to EntryType.

However, assuming we can assume that this is not actually as undefined as C++ wish it to be, then 129 is from:

`Entry=40` - which is in binary format on your system `28 00 00 00` (less significant byte first).

With `LineDescriptor.EntryType = 0x81;` you changed first byte: `81 00 00 00` - so your printout for Entry is now 129.

Make this experiment and you get other result:

TLineDescriptor LineDescriptor;

```
LineDescriptor.Entry = 256;
LineDescriptor.EntryType = 0x81;

cout << LineDescriptor.Entry << " " << unsigned(LineDescriptor.EntryType) 
     << endl;
>> 385  129
```

Comment: Thank you for the experiment, it makes the inner workings much more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is not wrong, the union will hold **either** the int or the struct. When you assign the value `0x81` to the EntryType field, the integer you previously assigned to `Entry` will be overwritten, which is why when you `cout` both fields, you get the same quantity appearing for both, one as an int (129) and one as a char (ü). Both have the hex value `0x81`.

Answer (score 1):

It holds an `int` and a `struct` at the **same** time, and both of the occupy the same memory space. By accessing `TLineDescriptor::Entry`, you interpret those 4 bytes as the `int`. If you access it through the `struct`, you interpret it as 4 `unsigned char`s.

```
LineDescriptor.Entry = 40;
```

This sets the 4 bytes to an `int` value of 40. In small endian system this means that first byte is 40, the other 3 bytes are 0.

```
LineDescriptor.EntryType = 0x81;
```

This sets the first byte to value 129 (0x81). (In small endian system this means, that the value of `Entry` is now 129 as well, provided you have the rest set to 0).

Regarding the different output: when you output the EntryType, it is displayed as a character instead of number. Try:

```
cout << LineDescriptor.Entry << " " << static_cast<int>(LineDescriptor.EntryType) << endl;
```